# Logical nullish assignment. Unexpected token '??='

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running this code with node.js:

```
const tasksSorted = {};
tasksSorted[0] ??= {};
```

Which I believe its valid.
I get the error:

```
tasksSorted[0] ??= {}; 
               ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
```

In the browser I can use the `??=` [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

Comment: What version of Node? It's not supported before Node 14 - wait, no make that 15

Comment: version v14.17.5. Thanks for your comment

Comment: The `??` operator is in 14, but `??=` requires 15

Comment: I just recently updated node, downloaded the latest .msi with that version. Checked for the latest .msi just now and it is the node-v14.17.6-x64.msi... so there are more recent versions that the latest .msi I guess, are they??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment#browser_compatibility), `Logical nullish assignment` is available for Node.js **15.0.0**

Comment: thanks for your answer. Latest know version is v14.17.6 from the node oficial [downloads](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). How can I get the latest?

Comment: thanks @Majed Badawi I noticed. Is it adviced to use the LTS version?

Comment: You're welcome. For a production environment yes.